# Does the System.Deployment namespace have a UWP equivalent?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a line in my code which checks

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
```

and I am wondering what the equivalent would be for UWP, as `System.Deployment` doesn't appear to exist for these type of projects. Has anyone any idea?

Comment: No there is no equivalent of the same in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

The `IsNetworkDeployed` check was specific for ClicOnce deployed applications ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Windows 10 Fall Creators Update introduced [Web Install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/installing-uwp-apps-web#web-install-experience-on-previous-versions-of-windows-10a-nameweb-install-experiencea), which is analogous to ClickOnce and enables [automatic updates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/09/27/automated-app-updates-with-appinstaller-file/) to your app as well.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will in all certainty use it in the future.  My original code snippet just detected the difference between running my app locally (for testing purposes) when it showed 'Not deployed' and when I had uploaded it to my website i.e. I was running it 'remotely' and it then showed 'Deployed'.  So, yes, I accept its a 'ClickOncey' thing, and I will try and replicate it when I have delved into Web Install.  Cheers

Comment: If that solved your question, please consider marking the answer as solution so that the question appears as solved.

Comment: Still checking it out ...!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, but after furtling around for much of the day I'm going to use:

Windows.ApplicationModel.Package

which more or less does the job for me, as I can pick out the version info from that and I can also deduce whether my app is 'deployed' or not.  Cheers